# Getting command line arguements passed to NSIS compiled exe

Tags: nsis

How to get all the 3 command line arguements passed to my NSIS compiled exe in variables so that I can use those parameters to `Exec(ute)` another exe.

For example -  `start abc.exe "test.txt" "-1"` is the command passed to my NSIS compiled exe where "abc" is exe name and "test.txt" and "-1" are the two arguements.

How to get both of them as different variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [GetOptions](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Includes/FileFunc/GetOptions.md) macro, which allows you getting the parameters when passed in a certain way. Unless you want to adapt your current commandline parameters, [GetParameters](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Includes/FileFunc/GetParameters.md) might suit you better, but you'll have to parse the parameters yourself.

Comment: Thanks, `GetParameters` is perfect for my job.